# styling adjustments to woo commerce shop page

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce

Can anyone offer advice on how to make styling adjustments to my products on the shop page? I find that they are too close together and I'd like to space them out a bit. Also, the product titles, being of different lengths, creates a bit of a chaotic appearance where the 'Add to cart' buttons are not positioned uniformly on a straight line. Obviously, this is caused by the varying length product titles and the ratings element. I just need to know what function to look in to style these elements. The site itself is just a test. It takes awhile to load, probably because the servers on the hosting platform are slow. 
http://www.cjbergin.com/wordpress

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The spacing of the products can be changed by having a bigger margin on the classes:

```
.woocommerce ul.products li.product, .woocommerce-page ul.products li.product
```

The product titles being different heights can be fixed by adding a `height: 20px;` (change that value you suit your needed).  to the following classes:

```
.woocommerce ul.products li.product h3, .woocommerce-page ul.products li.product h3
```

Comment: Thanks Howlin. Your advice helped me format the margins between the product images. As far as the issue with the titles, I decided that I would just make them uniform in size and contained on one line. I was thinking that perhaps I would modify the structure of the html which would have required locating the proper file but that would involve more trouble. This works for me.